# Custom configuration and resolving only compile dependencies

Tags: gradle, groovy, plugins, configuration, dependencies

i'm currently writing a small plugin but i'm stuck when i want to get a list of all dependencies that are used.

what i'm doing
inside the plugin i create a new configuration

```
def config = project.configurations.create(sourceSet.getTaskName('foo', 'bar'))
```

in the `build.gradle` that uses the plugin i add some dependencies to this configuration

```
dependencies {
  fooTestBar(project(':module'))
}
```

and in `module/build.gradle` i have

```
plugins {
  id 'java-library'
}
dependencies {
  implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4')
  api('org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.11.RELEASE')
}
```

when i now do the following in the plugin

```
List<ResolvedArtifact> = config.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.allModuleArtifacts.flatten()
```

i get the artifacts from both declarations in `:module`, but what i'm interested in is only the api dependency, means the one that is also used when compiling the project

it looks like the entire configurations is treated as a `runtime` configuration, so i have all artifacts including the transitive ones from both declarations, instead of only the api one including the transitive ones from api

until now i was not able to find any way to see if a resolved dependency / artifact is of type api which i do not want to have in my result list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to add the attribute for the usage

```
config.attributes {
    attribute( Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named( Usage, Usage.JAVA_API ) )
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_model.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_attributes.html

thanks Chris Doré on https://discuss.gradle.org/t/custom-configuration-and-resolving-only-compile-dependencies/38891